# jQueryMobile popup error 3 times and then back navigation

Tags: jquery, web-applications, jquery-mobile, mobile, popup

I have a really weird problem with my mobile web app. I have been working on it for several months and all of a sudden this problem comes along. You can call the problem **"3 strikes, you're out!"**.

I use:

- jQuery - 1.7.1
- jQueryMobile - 1.2.0

EDIT:
1. When I close my popup I get this error message:

```
XHR finished loading: "http://192.168.0.67/".
  f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send
  f.extend.ajax 
  a.mobile.loadPage 
  a.mobile.changePage 
  a.mobile.navreadyDeferred.done.a.mobile._handleHashChange 
  a.extend.onPopState 
  f.event.dispatch 
  f.event.add.h.handle.i 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '_trigger' of undefined 
  z 
  a.mobile.changePage 
  a.mobile.changePage.a.mobile.loadPage.done.fail.m 
  f.Callbacks.n 
  f.Callbacks.o.fireWith 
  f.Callbacks.o.fire 
  a.mobile.loadPage.a.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages.h.isSameDomain.a.ajax.success
  f.Callbacks.n 
  f.Callbacks.o.fireWith 
  w 
  f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d
```

1. Second time nothing special happends.
2. But the third time I close the popup - The browser goes back in the navigation to the previous webpage!!!

I do not want to change the page, but I presume that is what jQuery wants. How to I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer solved my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13699396/1340601

The problem was that the jQueryMobile popup was handling the browser history. I turned it of globally (in mobileinit) which solved the problem.

```
$.mobile.popup.prototype.options.history = false;
```