# Popup widget JQM 1.4.4 on Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, hash, popup

I need help with a problem with some of my popup (external).

Some since all other work as they should 
This problem only occurs on Android I try on Iphone emulator, everything is ok 
No error in the consol
Outline ==>

Mobile (Android 4.4.2 Sony E1) in a package Phonegap,

Open popup by clicking on an item inject: 
First opening all goes well 
To close, back button or delete icon. 
Second opening on the same element. 
The overlay appears but not the popup 
All attempts to openings following the same popup are a failure, unless the page is refreshed.

It is possible to open another popup.

Browser (Chrome) 
Open popup by clicking on an item inject: 
First opening goes well 
To close you have to click twice outside the popup. (No back brower, random behavior) 
Second opening all goes well 
Second closing everything is ok too.

My popup not working

```
<div data-role="popup"  id="popupphoto"  data-history="true" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-corners="false" >
<a href="#" data-rel="back"  class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a><img class="popphoto" id="popimg"  max-width="100%" max-height="100%" alt="Dossier"></div>
```

To open

```
$("#popupphoto").popup().popup("open");
```

My popup working all times

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popschool"  data-history="true" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="a"  data-tolerance="15,15" class="ui-content"><a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left">Close</a>

<p id="ind" style="font-style: italic;"></p>
<form>
</form>
<div class="center" >Schoolby</div>
```

To open

```
$("#popschool").popup().popup("open");
```

so I try to reproduce the same situations for both popup ==> failure

I also try to change data-history = "false" only change its behavior on the browser, it works very well for once. Mobile that does not change, more I need to be able to impact on the backbutton.

I try with the event pagecreate and enhanceWithin ==> failure

I tried to add a class = "ui-content" ==> failure

I think there has to do with the hash but I'm not really good at her so I have not found

PS: As you can see, this is an image the button to open, by clicking on the enlarged, just trying to find a solution I do not have all the image that is displayed in the popup even at the first opening (except browser) 
I lose hope ^^

I have not managed to reproduce the same situation on JS Fiddle sorry, I know it is important but that's why I try to be accurate

[Same problem](https://developer.tizen.org/fr/forums/web-application-development/popup-doesnt-appear-second-time-around?langredirect=1)

[Same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907944/closing-jquery-mobile-new-popup-cause-page-to-refresh-uselessly)

[Same problem](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5991)

[Same problem](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4272)

Comment: are you initializing the popups before opening them? you shouldn't use `.popup().popup("open")`, `.popup("open")` is enough. For external popups, you need to initialize them on first run and prior to opening them e.g. `$(function () { $("[data-role=popup]").popup() });` this will initialize/create all external popups.

Comment: I have always believed that popup().popup('open'); it was for initialization. I try and return. Thks

Comment: However, no difference in browser and mobile. Same behaviour

Comment: then it's a browser/platform issue.

Comment: The Webview Chrome has problems in this version of android, I think you are right and it could come from this environment. However this does not explain that I do now, still on the same version, the picture is no displayed, only the delete icon. Anarchic behavior that we could not provide? the code does not change